# "If" Statement Acting Like "While" Loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I've started creating a Discord bot. Here's the problem: the bot is spamming. I want him to send only one message when the condition is true. I'm using an `if` statement, but it acts like a `while` loop. Here's the code:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const token = 'TotallyNotMyRealToken';

client.login(token);

client.on('message', message => 
{
    if(message.content.includes("text"))
    {
        message.channel.send(" reply text");
    }
})
```

When I type "text" (for example), it sends "reply" until the script stops.
Could you please help me solve the issue?

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe discord.js is a node.js module.  You'll have better response by tagging node.js on your post.

Comment: You receive a message and unconditionally send another one. Which you also receive and send a reply again, and again, and again, ...

Comment: A shot in the dark: you are creating more than one client, they are all responding to the same event. You can verify (or rule out) this scenario by `console.log`ging some message immediately before `client.on`. If it appears more than once, you'll know where to look.

Comment: I've never used discord really but it's probably not a good idea to post your token also

Comment: @zerkms unless the message he replies with contains `text`, he should be good. If it does, it's hilarious.

Comment: you should probably exclude the sender from receiving its own message

Comment: @walroar thanks I'll think about it next time, now the problem is fixed

Comment: @vzwick it does, and I feel very dumb

Comment: sometimes you just need another set of eyes on your code .. happens to everyone ;)

Comment: @G-Man I'll try to find a way, thanks ;)

Comment: @Francefire don't beat yourself up about it - we've all been there. At least you didn't delete a production database.

Comment: @Francefire also, if that token was indeed real, you should invalidate it immediately. It will remain visible in the edit history of the question indefinitely.

Comment: @vzwick it's real but it's a test bot on a test server I will generate a new token, thanks for warning me ;)

Comment: @francefire you can check the message author https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=author to get the message user https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User to get the message client https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=client to compare to your client to not respond to itself

Comment: @MicFin Thanks, couldn't be more detailed <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending a message "reply text" which itself includes the word "text".

Change your example to use a different phrase.

```
client.on('message', message => 
{
    if(message.content.includes("text"))
    {
        message.channel.send(" this is a reply");
    }
})
```

Additionally, upon further discussion in the comments, if you would like a client to ignore its own messages, you could try something like:

```
client.on('message', message => 
{
    if(message.content.includes("text") && message.author.user.id !== client.user.id)
    {
        message.channel.send(" reply text");
    }
})
```

See https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=client

Comment: So I tried your solution and it didn't work so I used the console.log to help me find the problem and it seems like both message.client.user.id and client.user.id gave the same value and found out that I should use message.author.user.id and it works thanks ;)

Comment: Congrats!  Nice troubleshooting!

Answer (score 2):

After reading again my code, the problem is that the replies contains "text".

I found a solution :

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const token = 'NDA1ODQxMjg5NzU0NTc0ODQ5.DUqQww.HwSaa8TagR1mMGsVpdMDUm6-7tI';

bot.login(token);

bot.on('message', message => 
{    
   messageInput = message.content.toLowerCase();
   botId = bot.user.discriminator
   userId = message.author.discriminator
   console.log(botId)
   console.log(userId)
   console.log(messageInput)
    if(userId !== botId)
    {
        if(messageInput.includes("text"))
        {
            message.channel.send(" reply text ");
    }
}
```

})

Comment: `if (message.content.includes("text") && message.client.user.id !== client.user.id)` ;)